# Shouldn't a margin of auto push an element to the farthest it can go by filling in available whitespace?

Tags: css, flexbox

[Image of my current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evXte.png)

I'm learning flexbox, and I am trying to create a common layout that is found with dashboard kind of templates. These kinds of templates contain a main navigation menu on the left (the sidebar), a top navigation menu for things like user notifications or site themes, and a main content area below the top navigation menu.

The problem that I am facing is that one of my nav list items "B" (it has a white border around it for visibility) is for some unknown reason not being pushed to the bottom of the "purple" div.

I set the height to both the `nav` and the `ul` elements to have a height of 100% so that they take up as much vertical space as the body does. So from my understanding adding a `margin-top: auto` should in fact push B all the way to the bottom.

Is there a fundamental issue with my understanding? And am I on the right track to implementing this kind of theme correctly?

Thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#left {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 5rem;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-left,
.top-right {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#right {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="./project.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="left" class="column">
    <div class="top-left">
      Logo
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="column">
    <div class="top-right">
      Top right
    </div>
    <div>
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS code is correct but you are applying it to wrong element. The `ul` should get the flex box property so that all `li` items are displayed as columns. Apply flex property to `ul`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#left {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 5rem;
}

.column  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-left,
.top-right {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#right {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="./project.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="left" class="column">
    <div class="top-left">
      Logo
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="column">
    <div class="top-right">
      Top right
    </div>
    <div>
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use `margin-top:auto` try the following:

```
ul {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

You can also try in other ways like :

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

And by **grid** :

```
ul {
  display: grid;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get B pushed to the bottom by adding the following CSS properties to the `ul` element:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

I am still not sure why this was needed.